# What is the query to display the contents from 2 tables without duplicate data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as below

```
forum_t (forum_id PK, question,description).

forum_answer (forum_answer_id PK,comment,forum_id).
```

Now I want the result by combining these two tables to get question, description, and comment for particular forum_id(which is primary key in first table and foreign key in second table).

Comment: Unless you aggregate the `comment` column, you will always get duplicate `question`/`description` columns.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT question,description,comment
FROM
  forum_t 
  INNER JOIN 
  forum_answer
  ON forum_t.forum_id=forum_answer.forum_id
WHERE
  forum_t.forum_id={your forum id}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates, use `DISTINCT` keyword, but you will not get a single record per each question as you may have many answers and comments.

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.forum_id,F.question,F.description,A.comment
FROM forum_t F INNER JOIN forum_answer A on F.forum_id = A.forum_id
WHERE F.forum_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get one line per question, then you'll have to use some sort of aggregate function.

First the count (the number of answers per question).

```
select q.forum_id, q.question, q.description, count(*) as answer_count 
from forum_t q
inner join forum_answer a on (q.forum_id = a.forum_id)
where q.forum_id between 1 and 10  -- first 10 questions
group by q.forum_id
```

If you want the actual answers, you can use group_concat and put then together

```
select 
  q.forum_id
  , q.question
  , q.description
  , count(*) as answer_count
  , group_concat(a.comment) as comments_in_csv_form 
from forum_t q
inner join forum_answer a on (q.forum_id = a.forum_id)
where q.forum_id between 1 and 10  -- first 10 questions
group by q.forum_id
```

You can now explode the comments using php or whatever langauge you use clientside.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat